# Ошибка с установкой Delve. Невозможно кастануть алиас к родительскому типу данных

Tags: golang

Ос: `Win10 x64`
Go: `go version go1.12.9 windows/amd64`

Хочу установить Delve, но выдает ошибку `cannot use context (type *winutil.CONTEXT) as type *_CONTEXT in argument to _GetThreadContext`. `_CONTEXT`  это алиас к `winutil.CONTEXT` , почему не хочет кастить - я не пойму, такая же проблема и в любых других пакетах, когда не может кастануть алиас к родительскому типу данных.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос версию го и ОС.

Comment: @Ainar-G добавил.

Comment: @Mothership А как вы объявляете alias?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов Думаю, имеется в виду [вот это](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/4c9a72e486f1f0d0c90ecede8415a871dced8117/pkg/proc/native/syscall_windows.go#L105).

Comment: @Ainar-G верно, это тот зловещий кусок.